# Selenium Java - Writing the hashmap values to excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the hashmap values for writing the testcase status in excel file, but it is not writing the data to the excel. Here is my code -

```
    public void readData() throws Exception {
    String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test Data";
    String fileName = "editSubscriptions.xls";
    String sheetName = "datapool";

    File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    Workbook workbook = null;

    String fileExtName = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."));

    if (fileExtName.equals(".xlsx")) {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    } else if (fileExtName.equals(".xls")) {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    }
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() - sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            System.out.println(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(row.getCell(0).toString());
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(row.getCell(1).toString());
            driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
                WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
                wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Login")));
                hm.put(row.getCell(0).toString(), "Pass");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                hm.put(row.getCell(0).toString(), "Fail");
                driver.get("http://www.openclinica.com");
            }
        }
    }
    Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
    for (String key: keys){
        System.out.println("Value of "+key+" is: "+hm.get(key));

        String filePath1 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test Data";
        String fileName1 = "editSubscriptions1.xls";
        String sheetName1 = "datapool";

        File file1 = new File(filePath1 + "\\" + fileName1);
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
        Workbook workbook1 = null;

        String fileExtName1 = fileName1.substring(fileName1.indexOf("."));

        if (fileExtName1.equals(".xlsx")) {
            workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        } else if (fileExtName1.equals(".xls")) {
            workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(fis1);
        } 
        Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet(sheetName1);
        int rowCount1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum() - sheet1.getFirstRowNum();

        for (int i=1; i < rowCount1; i++){
            Cell cell = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(2);
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(hm.put(key, hm.get(key)));
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add the status as Pass or Fail to the excel sheet by using hashmap key. I am able to print the status in the console, but that is not transforming to the excel sheet.

Value of HemaSai is: Fail
Value of MoulikaNimmala is: Pass
Value of Keshav is: Fail

Please help me in resolving the problem..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the outcome in the excelFile?

Comment: username                 password                   Result
MoulikaNimmala $Ai11081988
HemaSai                 sai11081988
Keshav                 sai30041990

Comment: is this in one row? i can't imagine at the moment which of these are the rows and which the cells

Comment: username(0,0) MoulikaNimmala(1,0) HemaSai(2,0)  Keshav(3,0) password(0,1) $Ai11081988(1,1)  sai11081988(2,1)  sai30041990(3,1) result(0,2) fail(1,2) pass(2,2) fail(3,2)

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowCount1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum() - sheet1.getFirstRowNum();

    for (int i=1; i < rowCount1; i++){
        Cell cell = sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(2);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(hm.put(key, hm.get(key)));
    }
```

your loop should start at index 0 according to the [doc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow%28int%29).

it looks like you never get into a loop, as you start at index 1 but your rowcount is initial 0 if you start with an empty sheet.

edit: after the comments, i would go for a solution like this (untested!)

```
 Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
String filePath1 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Test Data";
    String fileName1 = "editSubscriptions1.xls";
    String sheetName1 = "datapool";

    File file1 = new File(filePath1 + "\\" + fileName1);
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
    Workbook workbook1 = null;

    String fileExtName1 = fileName1.substring(fileName1.indexOf("."));

    if (fileExtName1.equals(".xlsx")) {
        workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis1);
    } else if (fileExtName1.equals(".xls")) {
        workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(fis1);
    } 
    Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet(sheetName1);
    int rowCount1 = sheet1.getLastRowNum() - sheet1.getFirstRowNum(); //set rowNumber to the last already set one
for (String key: keys){ //for every key write the name in column 1 and the result in column 2
    rowcount1++; //start at the next free row

    Cell cell1 = sheet1.createRow(rowCount1).createCell(1);
        Cell cell2 = sheet1.getRow(rowCount1).createCell(2);
        cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell1.setCellValue(key));
        cell2.setCellValue(hm.get(key)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have intentionally used index to start at 1 because my 0th column in the excel file is named as Result/Status. So i would like the status Pass or Fail to start from row -1, column - 2

Comment: but as far as i understand it, you are iterating over the rows in this loop mentioned above

Comment: This code holds the value of the status either Pass or Fail - 
Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
    for (String key: keys){
        System.out.println("Value of "+key+" is: "+hm.get(key));
  
At the end I have used the excel sheet to iterate through the no. of rows in the excel starting at index 1 of column 2.

So I expect for every key found in Set the value should be passed to the cell value in the excel sheet1. If this approach is not correct?
Please re-commend me a better approach.

Comment: but you are doing that for every entry in the map.

Comment: Now i understand it tries to iterate for every entry in the map, how can i use the hashmap key-value outside the Set loop?